# Trying to list all S3 bucket with its respective lifecycle policies in a csv file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Trying to list all S3 bucket with its respective lifecycle policies in a csv file.

Able to list S3 as expected. But not able to list its respective lifecycle policies.

If the bucket has S3 life cycle policy, it should list the policy. If it has no policy, it should say "No Policy" in the csv.

Expecting Some thing like this in a csv:

```
Bucket 1    PolicyDetail
Bucket 2    NoPolicy
Bucket 3    PolicyDetail
```

```
def main():
    with open('S3.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow([
            'Account Name',
            'Region',
            'Bucket Name',
            'Policy'

        ])
        with open('role.json') as ec2_file:
            ec2_data = json.load(ec2_file)
        region_list = ['eu-west-1']
        for region in region_list:
            for index in range(len(ec2_data['Items'])):
                Account_Number = ec2_data['Items'][index]['Aws_Account_Number']
                Account_Name = ec2_data['Items'][index]['Acc_Name']
                ARN = ec2_data['Items'][index]['ARN']
                b = get_assume_arn_to_keys(Account_Number,Account_Name,ARN)
                ds_client = boto3.client('s3',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id=b[1],aws_secret_access_key=b[2],aws_session_token=b[3])


                s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

                for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
                    writer.writerow([
                        Account_Name,
                        region,
                        bucket.name,
                        ds_client.get_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket='k')
                        #s3.GetLifecycleConfiguration()

main()
```

***Code Updated as per the answers given below****

Please help on this. 
Tried to get it for single bucket.. But not for the list..

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the bucket policy like this:

```
ds_client.get_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket.name)
```

For lifecyle, try:

```
ds_client.get_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket=bucket.name)
```

The above will return a dictionary of data if a policy is found.

Comment: `get_bucket_lifecycle` will return that for you.

Comment: Correct.. But it throwing error "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketLifecycle operation: Access Denied" though I have administrator access.

Comment: ds_client.get_bucket_lifecycle(Bucket=bucket.name).. If I am giving the single bucket name(eg:bucket123), its showing the policy in dictionary as expected. But If I use "bucket.name", its throwing error " An error occurred (NoSuchLifecycleConfiguration) when calling the GetBucketLifecycle operation: The lifecycle configuration does not exist"